# Connect to RabbitMQ (Amqp) via ssh gateway

Tags: ssh, vpn, port-forwarding, bastion

I have the following situation: 

`DevMachine (D) need to connect to a gateway/bastion server (G)
and then be able to talk to another server serving RabbitMQ (R) traffic on port 5672.`

I tried using an ssh tunnel to the gateway: `ssh -L 5672:localhost:5672 G` and next I want the gateway instance to let me connect to `R`'s 5672. How do I accomplish that? I feel like I am missing a step here.

What I want: `D ->G -> R`. What I am getting is `D ->G`. If I had a rabbitmq instance running locally on `G` - this works but what I want is to essentially use `G` as a VPN.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to connect to remote host, you need to use its name, not the `localhost`:

```
ssh -L 5672:R:5672 G
```

in this way, you should be able to access host `R` on `localhost:5672`.

Comment: I think thats the right answer for my question - I have other VPN issues that I need to fix. Thanks! @Jakuje